# Implementing Data Access Layer in MVVM (TCP)

Tags: mvvm, tcp, model

Most of MVVM and Data Access Layer articles explain WCF and DTO stuffs but My project never uses them but plain TCP/IP communication with server.

I've had models use Tcp/ip socket directly. However, I've been feeling that tcp/ip socket logic should be de-coupled with the models.

If so, I would like to know how to de-couple and implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always consider the Model the 'thing' that is delivered to me from a database, service, file, ... any repository, including a socket.

I'd wrap the socket in a repository of some sorts to get the data in a nice format that can be transformed into a ViewModel.

That said, if speed is the reason you are using sockets, the whole repository/model/viewmodel might prove to be too slow. Try and test as always.